# How to disable a command in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have recorded some steps from http://docs.seleniumhq.org/ using Selenium IDE. After recording I have save the file as SeleniumhqExample.html -> I ran it and it passed successfully. I want to disable/inactive one of the recorded commands in Selenium IDE.

I want to disable the following command:

```
<tr>
    <td>assertTitle</td>
    <td>SeIDE Release Notes · SeleniumHQ/selenium Wiki · GitHub</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

How can I disable that single command in Selenium IDE? Please see the image:
[image]

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this in the manner you want. The closest thing would be inputting a breakpoint before this step, but if it isn't a command at the end of your script, that would also exclude every step following it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Setting up the Breakpoint will stop the test execution in that point and test will stop there. But I want to stop an entire step/command and I like to proceed further steps.

Comment: Is there a reason you just don't want to delete it?

Comment: It might be needed for further use depends on individual to individual needs, that's why I don't want to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using HTML comments as . For example I want to disable the step assertTitle, follow the steps:

1. Go to "Source" Tab in Selenium IDE
2. Comments the specific step(s) as below:
   [image]
   Now the above step/command is disable and during running that step/command would be skipped and further steps/commands would be executed usually.

In the Table view disable/commented row should be shown as below:
[image: Table view of disabled row]